# FIlepicker : How to store the files into specified folder in S3

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, filepicker

I just integrated Filepicker.io SDK with my iPhone Application. In that if i upload the file from Social Networks(FaceBook, dropBox...) the files are directly uploaded into S3 bucket. The thing is, I would like to upload the files into specified path with in the S3. i already set the path but, the files are not uploaded into the specified path. it's uploading only into S3 Bucket. At the same time, if i upload the images which are already stored in  Device(Simulator) is uploading directly into the specified folder within the S3 Bucket. So, i would like to know how to save images in my own path with in S3 bucket.

If anyone give the solution for this, it will be helpful for me..